How to prevent Playwright to load non-textual contents?
I am trying to implement a crawler which will be responsible to crawl the given page. Here I don't want to crawl any non-textual items, not even want the headless browser to load it, as it is simply wasteful and unnecessarily increases the crawling time. To achieve this, I have added rules which should help it to get rid of those unwanted contents. But it is not working as expected. As from the log, I can clearly see some of the non-textual contents are loaded and taking more time to crawl:
... ... ...
 'playwright/request_count/resource_type/document': 1,
 'playwright/request_count/resource_type/font': 1,
 'playwright/request_count/resource_type/image': 20,
 'playwright/request_count/resource_type/script': 6,
 'playwright/request_count/resource_type/stylesheet': 3,
 'playwright/response_count': 30,
 'playwright/response_count/method/GET': 30,
 'playwright/response_count/resource_type/document': 1,
 'playwright/response_count/resource_type/font': 1,
 'playwright/response_count/resource_type/image': 20,
 'playwright/response_count/resource_type/script': 5,
 'playwright/response_count/resource_type/stylesheet': 3,
... ... ...

How not to load them? I am using Scrapy along with Playwright to make it able to work on dynamic contents.
Following is my code:
from scrapy.spiders import Spider, Rule
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.linkextractors import IGNORED_EXTENSIONS
import tldextract
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider


class LinkCrawlerSpiderSelective(Spider):
    name = 'link_crawler_selective'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        self.start_urls = ["https://books.toscrape.com/"] # Enter URLs to crawl
        self.hard_limit = 100 # Maximum how many items to crawl
        self.total_page_visited = 0

        # allow_domains = self.start_urls: because we only want to take the start_url and/or pages 
        # which are direct children of it. Even if other pages are accessible from the start_url
        # which do not share the same context path, we will not take them.
        self.allowed_domains = []
        for url in self.start_urls:
            domain = tldextract.extract(url).registered_domain
            self.allowed_domains.append(domain)
        
        self._rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains = self.allowed_domains, deny_extensions = IGNORED_EXTENSIONS))]


    def start_requests(self):
        # Define the initial URL(s) to scrape
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, meta=dict(
                playwright=True,
                playwright_include_page=True,
                errback=self.errback,
            ))


    def parse(self, response):

        self.total_page_visited += 1
        if self.total_page_visited > self.hard_limit:
            raise CloseSpider(f'Hard limit exceeded. Maximum number of pages to crawl is set to be: {self.hard_limit}')

        # Extract all text nodes except those within script and style tags
        text = ' '.join(response.xpath('//*[not(self::script) and not(self::style)]/text()').getall())

        yield {
            "link": response.url,
            "text": "\n".join([" ".join(str(l).split()) for l in text.split("\n") if str(l).strip()])
        }

    async def errback(self, failure):
        page = failure.request.meta["playwright_page"]
        await page.close()

Following is the settings.py:
# settings.py

import os

SPIDER_MODULES = [f"{os.path.split(os.getcwd())[-1]}.spiders"]

# Set settings whose default value is deprecated to a future-proof value
REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION = "2.7"
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = "utf-8"


#### FOR PLAYWRIGHT
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
    "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
}
PLAYWRIGHT_DEFAULT_NAVIGATION_TIMEOUT = 60 * 1000  # 10 seconds

TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2  # minimum download delay 
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True


# Scrapy requires this reactor
from scrapy.utils.reactor import install_reactor
install_reactor('twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor')


Thanks wRAR for the information. This problem is solved by implementing a method which will block non-textual contents. Keep this code inside settings.py. Following is the code (modify the extensions or types as needed):
def should_abort_request(request):
    print(f"Request resource type: {request.resource_type}, URL: {request.url}")

    return (
        # Block images
        request.resource_type in ["image", "font", "media", "stylesheet", "script"]
        or any(ext in request.url for ext in [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif", ".webp", ".svg", ".ico"])
        # Block media (audio/video)
        or any(ext in request.url for ext in [".mp3", ".mp4", ".avi", ".mov", ".wav", ".flv", ".mkv", ".webm"])
        # Block fonts
        or any(ext in request.url for ext in [".woff", ".woff2", ".ttf", ".eot", ".otf"])
        # Block stylesheets
        or ".css" in request.url
        # Block scripts
        or ".js" in request.url
        # Block xhr and fetch requests
        or request.resource_type in ["xhr", "fetch"]
    )

PLAYWRIGHT_ABORT_REQUEST = should_abort_request

